# Oracle Data Pump (expdp and impdp)

Tags: oracle11g, remote-access, datapump

Currently i'm using `expdp and impdp` to export and import my schema in my pc. i have wrote two scripts to export and import and run that scripts using batch file when i need.

Now i'm going to host my application on a Remote server. i need to backup schema in my Remote server as i'm doing on my pc.(using scripts, call the scripts using batch file when i need).

Currently i'm using below syntax

```
expdp scott/tiger schemas=SCOTT directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=SCOTT.dmp logfile=expdpSCOTT.log

impdp scott/tiger schemas=SCOTT directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=SCOTT.dmp logfile=impdpSCOTT.log
```

But how could i export and import from Remote server ?

Answer (score 0):

You can run datapump exports and imports on a remote server by using the `dbms_datapump` [supplied package](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_datpmp.htm#ARPLS356).

However, this will only export/import files on the remote server itself. So you will need access to this server if you want to import dumps from other databases, or copy this export to a separate database.

Note, datapump isn't actually a backup method. If you're using this for your backup and recovery strategy (as opposed to just copying data), you should be using [RMAN](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/backup.111/b28273/rcmsynta040.htm#RCMRF111).